# Повернуть изображение на 90 градусов

Tags: c++, изображения

У меня есть массив формата RGBARGBA... размера `4 * width * height + 1`, в котором записаны биты изображения (формат пнг, но думаю, здесь это не важно). Я хочу повернуть изображение на 90 градусов налево.

```
void turnLeft() {
        std::vector<std::vector<Pixel>> temp(height, std::vector<Pixel>(width));
        for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
            for (int j = 3; j < width - 4; j += 4) {
                temp[i][j] = {rawPixels[i * (4 * width) + j - 3], rawPixels[i * (4 * width) + j - 2],
                              rawPixels[i * (4 * width) + j - 1], rawPixels[i * (4 * width) + j]};
            }
        }
        int m = (int) temp.size(), n = (int) temp[0].size();
        std::vector<std::vector<Pixel>> tempTemp(n,
                                                 std::vector<Pixel>(m));
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                tempTemp[j][m - 1 - i] = temp[i][j];
            }
        }
        rawPixels.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < (int) tempTemp.size(); ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < (int) tempTemp[i].size(); ++j) {
                rawPixels.push_back(tempTemp[i][j].R);
                rawPixels.push_back(tempTemp[i][j].G);
                rawPixels.push_back(tempTemp[i][j].B);
                rawPixels.push_back(tempTemp[i][j].A);
            }
        }
        std::swap(width, height);
    }
```

Структура, описывающая пиксель:

```
struct Pixel {
    unsigned char R, G, B, A;

    Pixel() = default;

    Pixel(unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b, unsigned char a) {
        R = r;
        G = g;
        B = b;
        A = a;
    }
};
```

Если из кода непонятно, то опишу алгоритм. Сначала я пытаюсь перевести одномерный массив в матрицу, попутно сжимая 4 соседних числа (RGBA) в один элемент типа `Pixel`. После этого поворачиваю этот массив на 90 градусов и полученный пытаюсь трансформировать обратно в тот же одномерный формат. Я не хочу использовать для этого OpenCV. Пожалуйста, помогите, не работает совсем! С изображением происходит что угодно, кроме необходимого.

Comment: ¿А вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: так не нужно ничего сжимать. 4 байта однозначно "мапятся" на 4байтовый pixel. И не нужно лишнего копирования.

Comment: @KoVadim под сжатием я "мапание" и имел ввиду. Только вот ничего не работает.

Comment: @user7860670 с изображением происходят самые невероятные метаморфозы, но не поворот на 90 градусов.

Comment: а картинка имеет разную ширину-высоту? а также, Вы хотите развернуть "на месте"? или через отдельный массив

Comment: @KoVadim разную. Развернуть можно используя доп массив

Comment: если можно допмассив, тогда проще простого  - в двойном цикле просто пишем `res[y, width-x] = origing[x,y]` (но это с учетом пикселей)

Comment: @KoVadim можно подробнее?

Comment: написать двойной цикл по ширине и высоте?

Comment: Простите, вы читали код, приведенный в вопросе? Во-первых, я так и делаю, во-вторых, кроме этого нужно сделать еще несколько действий с изначальным массивом. Просто повернуть двумерный массив на 90 градусов я могу.

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается, это делалось простой формулой

```
void turnRight() {
        std::vector<unsigned char> output(rawPixels.size());
        for (int X = 0; X < width; ++X) {
            for (int Y = 0; Y < height; ++Y) {
                for (int chan = 0; chan < CHANNELS_COUNT; ++chan) {
                    output[(X * height + Y) * CHANNELS_COUNT + chan] = rawPixels[
                            ((height - 1 - Y) * width + X) * CHANNELS_COUNT + chan];
                }
            }
        }
        rawPixels = output;
        std::swap(width, height);
    }
```